# Delphi accessing c++ DLL only returning 5 Characters in a string

Tags: delphi, dll, netcdf

I am attempting to use a C .dll in Delphi and have translated the header file. I am coming unstuck when I attempt to return a string of characters from the .dll. The C definition of the function is:

```
EXTERNL int
nc_inq_path(int ncid, size_t *pathlen, char *path);
```

My Delphi equivalent for this is:

```
function nc_inq_path( ncid : Integer; var pathlen : Cardinal; var path : AnsiChar): Integer; cdecl; external 'netCDF.dll';
```

I have then used the above function as below

```
var
  ncid : Integer;
  res : Integer;
  pathlen : Cardinal;
  pathChar : AnsiChar;
  ppathChar : PansiChar;
  outstr : String;
begin
  res := nc_create(PAnsiChar(FILENAME), NC_CLOBBER, ncid);
  res := nc_inq_path(ncid, pathlen, pathChar);
  ppathChar := Addr(pathChar);
  outstr := Ppathchar;
end;
```

The variable outstr only holds the first 5 characterse of the path, i.e. "C:\Us".

If anyone can tell me why it is only giving me 5 charaters that would be great, and what I need to change to access the whole string?

Comment: You only allocate a single character so it's miracle that you receive more than one. You are surely expected to initialise pathlen before calling the function, so that the function knows how large an array you provided. And the path argument is an array. That's how you will allocate more than a single character. You will need to read the documentation of the library. It's never enough just to use the header file and try to guess the interface. It will be valuable also to read some code that calls winapi functions, GetWindowText. That will provide a template for how to use similar functions.

Comment: You are wrong with this part: `var path : AnsiChar` in function declaration, it must be `const path: PAnsiChar`.

Comment: [DLL dos and don’ts](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html) by Rudy Velthuis

Comment: Thanks David, Zed, and DC, that was the help I needed. I went back and read some dll implementations properly rather than hacking around in the dark and got it working. Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
function nc_inq_path( ncid : Integer; var pathlen : Cardinal; var path : AnsiChar): Integer; cdecl; external 'netCDF.dll';
```

should change to

```
function nc_inq_path( ncid : Integer; var pathlen : Cardinal; path : PAnsiChar): Integer; cdecl; external 'netCDF.dll';
```

and I think these code would work

```
var
  ncid : Integer;
  res : Integer;
  pathlen : Cardinal;
  path : array [0..255] of AnsiChar;
  outstr : String;
begin
  pathlen = 256;
  res := nc_create(PAnsiChar(FILENAME), NC_CLOBBER, ncid);
  res := nc_inq_path(ncid, pathlen, path);
  outstr := path;
end;
```

Comment: Hard to be 100% sure that `path` will be null terminated. Perhaps the length will be returned in `pathlen`. Really the asker must read the documentation for this library and not guess as to how to call it, as you also have done.

Comment: I have read the documentation properly now and the pathlen is returned by the function. I have initialised a big enough array to take the path lengths (and caught errors if the file name is truely stupidly big) and then read characters back out to the length that is returned. Thanks for all the help